# Palindromic perfect squares between two inputed integers

Tags: java

I need to write a program that outputs all palindromic perfect squares between two input values (`X` and `Y`) in Java:

```
Enter the starting point X:
Enter the ending point Y:
The palindromic perfect squares are as follow:
```

Comment: ... and what code have you written so far?

Comment: this is not homeworkoverflow :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to break your problem down into components:

- As for the I/O, there are a number of alternatives in Java. For something simple like this, [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) would probably work best.
- Once you have your two integers `x` and `y`, you'll need to perform a certain test for all integers in the range they define. A simple [`for`-loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) should do.
- Now you need to check if each integer you encounter...

  - is a palindrome. You can do this fairly trivially with string operations (see [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)).
  - is a perfect square - meaning its square-root is also an integer (hint). If these two conditions are satisfied, print the integer.

Comment: +1 for understanding the question ;-)